# Price of train tickets in Geneva

Tags: trains, switzerland, price, geneva

Is there a price difference when buying a train ticket in Geneva Airport automatic machine or pre ordering online?

Comment: As a small side note. You get a free local transport ticket when arriving at Geneva airport. (There's a machine dispensing them before customs at the luggage collection area). So If all you want is getting to Geneva, you can use those instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiss Railways offers SuperSaver tickets that are available, I believe, only on their website or mobile app, with non-refundable advance purchase. These are limited in number and definitely not available on all routes. At least according to their site, they are not available at the station, neither from an agent nor from a machine.

As of 2013, there was no difference in price between the agent and the nearby machine for a train that was leaving in a few minutes.

Comment: Note that those tickets are for a specific train at a specific time, contrary to tickets you buy at the station (or the regular tickets online) which can be used on any train, which gives you a lot more flexibility, something important when taking a train right after a flight.

Answer (score 2):

Normal tickets are the same price, regardless of where or when they are bought. So it does not matter if you do this on line, at a manned ticket counter, or from a ticket vending machine. Such tickets are flexible, valid on any train on the route you purchased.
Be aware that you cannot buy tickets on the train however.

Supersaver tickets are cheaper, but can only be bought on line or using the phone app. They are also not flexible.

When arriving by plane and continuing to a destination in Switzerland that is a non trivial distance away from Geneva getting a Saver Day Pass may be a good option. This is a fairly new product that when booked in advance can be cheaper than just buying a normal ticket on arrival.

See: https://www.sbb.ch/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets-for-switzerland/1-day-travelpass/saver-day-pass.html